# How to use SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize() properly in SDL2?

Tags: sdl2, c, resolution

I want to handle different resolutions without altering any game objects. I tried using `SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize()` but I don't know how to implement it properly. Providing an example of implementing it would be really helpful (in C). I saw a [similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126395/how-to-handle-different-resolutions-in-sdl2) asked here years ago but I didn't understand that. I'm a beginner building my first project involving a few rectangles. This is my current code:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 480//p
#define WINDOW_WIDTH (16 * (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 9))

#define FRAME_TARGET_TIME (1000 / 75 /*FPS*/)

int last_frame_time = 0;
SDL_bool is_running = SDL_FALSE;
SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Window* window2 = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

int xA = 0, yA = 0, wA = 100, hA = 75, vA = 1000;
int xB = 0, yB = 0, wB = 100, hB = 75, vB = 1000;

SDL_bool initialize_window(void) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing SDL.\n");
        return SDL_FALSE;
    }
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(NULL, 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating SDL Window.\n");
        return SDL_FALSE;
    }
    window2 = SDL_CreateWindow(NULL, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN);
    if (!window2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating SDL Window2.\n");
        return SDL_FALSE;
    }
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (!renderer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating SDL Renderer.\n");
        return SDL_FALSE;
    }

    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(renderer, 1920, 1080);

    return SDL_TRUE;
}

void process_input(void) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            is_running = SDL_FALSE;
        }
        else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                is_running = SDL_FALSE;
                break;
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                break;
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                break;
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                break;
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                vA = -1000;
                break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                vA = 1000;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void setup(void) {

}

void update(void) {
    int time_to_wait = FRAME_TARGET_TIME - (SDL_GetTicks() - last_frame_time);

    if (time_to_wait > 0 && time_to_wait <= FRAME_TARGET_TIME) SDL_Delay(time_to_wait);

    float delta_time = (SDL_GetTicks() - last_frame_time) / 1000.0;

    last_frame_time = SDL_GetTicks();

    xA += vA * delta_time;

    if (xA < -wA) xA = WINDOW_WIDTH + wA;
    if (xA > WINDOW_WIDTH + wA) xA = -wA;

}


void render(void) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_Rect rectangleA = { xA, yA, wA, hA };
    SDL_Rect rectangleB = { xB, yB, wB, hB };

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rectangleA);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rectangleB);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void destroy_window(void) {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window2);
    SDL_Quit();
}



int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    xA = (WINDOW_WIDTH - wA) / 2;
    yA = (WINDOW_HEIGHT - hA) / 2;

    is_running = initialize_window();

    setup();

    while (is_running) {
        process_input();
        update();
        render();
    }

    destroy_window();

    return 0;
}```
````